# Understanding static member variables in javascript 6

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, closures

I don't understand because when I instantiate twice Gadget function object, the console print me final 2 not 1, counter  is incremented.

```
var Gadget = (function(){
    var counter = 0;
    return function(){ console.log( counter += 1 );}
})();

var g1 = new Gadget();
var g2 = new Gadget();
```

If I don't immediate execute function expression I don't get any output:

```
var Gadget = (function(){
    var counter = 0;
    return function(){ console.log( counter += 1 );}
}); // <---- not immediate execute expression
var g1 = new Gadget();
var g2 = new Gadget();
```

No output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first block of code.

```
var Gadget = (function(){
var counter = 0;
    return function(){ console.log( counter += 1 );}
})();

var g1 = new Gadget();
var g2 = new Gadget();
```

`Gadget` will be equal the internal function, `function(){ console.log( counter += 1 )`, and because it will capture the counter value by `Closure` feature.

So the `counter` will be increment by `Gadget` execution.

In the second section

```
var Gadget = (function(){
var counter = 0;
    return function(){ console.log( counter += 1 );}
}); // <---- not immediate execute expression
var g1 = new Gadget();
var g2 = new Gadget();
```

Because the function doesn't immediately execute, the `Gadget` function will equal the outer function, not the internal function.

Comment: ok how can the counter to be shared between two instance g1,g2? g1,g2 are separate variables, no? I accept your answer, I understand the counter variable is visible outside console.log function so, it is as global variable but not global at script file level because in closure? right?

Comment: It's not about `g1` and `g2`, it's about the `new Gadget()` execution, it's execution update the counter, Just imagine, that the `counter` variable is stored somewhere, and any `internal function` that uses it, can update it, it something like, if you have a global variable, and there is a function update this value, whenever this function execute will update the last result of the global value, I wish that you understand it now.

Comment: Yes "whenever this function execute will update the last result of the global value, I wish that you understand it now" Thank you.

Comment: Please, check this example and you can understand what I mean, the closure will work like that https://jsfiddle.net/7n6gxsp3/

Comment: I understand example  Ok it's not about g1 and g2, it's about Gadget execution. However I have a doubt... when call new Gadget() context closure isn't created but it is the same if counter equal two at the end. Why? I Thought that `(function(){ })` in two Gadget isn't the same.